# How to get last 5 elements from an xml file using java

Tags: java, xml, xslt

I have a XML file in the following format:

```
  <CodeSnippet>
  <Code tag="class eclipse">
  <Snippet>sample</Snippet>
  <TimeStamp>05/11/2014 13:50:36</TimeStamp>
  </Code>
  <Code tag="button java">
  <Snippet>Sample code</Snippet>
  <TimeStamp>05/11/2014 12:36:36</TimeStamp>
  </Code>
  .
  .
  .  
  </CodeSnippet>
```

I would like to know, how to retrieve the last 5 child nodes of the root node "CodeSnippet" and display the text inside the tag "Snippet".

Comment: You could use xQuery (query language for XML) to do.  There are java 3rd party libraries available for the same.  We could do the same using parsers as well.  But things with xQuery is bit easy

Comment: By "last", do you mean chronologically or by document order? If chronologically, what is the date format being used? "05/11/2014" is ambiguous.

Comment: @michael.hor257k.. "Last" meant the document order in xml file which i have shown above. Please do not worry about the timestamp as of now.

Comment: How large an input file are we talking?  If it's of the order of kB or MB then you can afford to load the whole file into memory and then extract the appropriate bits using DOM calls or XPath, but if it's GB then you'll need some kind of streaming approach.

Answer (score 1):

Get a learning of using XPATH expressions in java here http://howtodoinjava.com/2012/11/07/how-to-work-with-xpaths-in-java-with-examples/

For your specific problem get all the snippet nodes using xpath expression `//CodeSnippet/Snippet`. Once done run a for loop from nodes.length to nodes.length-5.

Comment: I am currently doing that only but want an efficient way to do it using xpath. Say, if i have 5000 entries in my xml file then performing the method you have mentioned would be tedious job right. It would reduce performance of the system. Correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: I'm parsing 300 xml files in less than 1 second. I don't think there would be any problem at all. Although, I don't know the performance you are looking for ;D

Comment: Ok even though its not really expensive but if still bothered, there are two ways. 1. use xpath.compile("count(//CodeSnippet/Code/Snippet)") to get the count and get last five elements compiling xpath 5 times with count, count-1 and so on. 2. use xpath.compile("//CodeSnippet/Code[last()]/Snippet/text()");, xpath.compile("//CodeSnippet/Code[last()-1]/Snippet/text()"); and so on 5 times.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

XSLT **1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"   
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <root>
        <xsl:for-each select="CodeSnippet/Code[position() > last() - 5]">
            <xsl:copy-of select="Snippet"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </root>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You didn't say what the exact format of output should be. The above will result in an XML document in the form of:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
  <Snippet>V</Snippet>
  <Snippet>W</Snippet>
  <Snippet>X</Snippet>
  <Snippet>Y</Snippet>
  <Snippet>Z</Snippet>
</root>
```

Comment: thanks for the piece of code. Will try and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good tutorial of XML Parsing for Java using three different technologies. In your case I would recommend you the DOM option, even if I see SAX the easiest one. Just try to make the changes you need for your case.

http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/05/parsing-xml-using-dom-sax-and-stax-parser-in-java.html

Have a nice code!

Answer (score 0):

If you can use an XPath 2.0 processor, you could use the following XPath:

```
subsequence(//Snippet,count(//Snippet)-5)
```